# Android Class Object problem

Tags: android

HI all,

actually i m new in android development.

i have one activity class and one simple class(Without Activity). in Simple class i m calling some web service and storing the response in array. after that this array i want to access in my activity class. m not able to make the object. how can i do that? i don't want to use bundle. as this array i want to access in more than one class.

please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The activity calls/creates the Simple class, right? Pass a reference to the activity object to the Simple class, have the Simple class call the activity back with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use static, but it depends of data.